# Selenium::Remote::Driver or WWW::Selenium

Tags: perl, selenium

Which one should I use for a new project?
What is the difference between them?

Comment: voted down, is that all you found out yet?

Comment: How to install Selenium::Remote::Driver or WWW::Selenium on Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both require the Selenium java-based server to be running (as far as I can manage anyway).

WWW::Selenium uses the older v1 protocol, but has more infrastructure surrounding it. The v2 Selenium server is backwards compatible.

::Driver uses v2 protocol and is newer.

There are differences between v1 and v2 interfaces but the basic idea is the same in both.

So - in summary - not a huge difference between them. I don't think you'd regret your choice whichever you picked.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between Selenium 1 and Selenium 2 (aka Selenium RC, Webdriver respectively) is the way they drive the browser:

Selenium RC injects javascript to drive the  browser while webdriver uses the browsers build in automation capabilities. What this means is that if you are using webdriver PLUS either the C# or Java bindings for example, you will not need the Selenium Server (unless you're not running your tests on the same machine as the browser).

As an FYI, the Selenium-Users as well as Webdriver groups in Google are great resources with an active community of participants. Most questions get answered there relatively quickly. Links below:

[Webdriver Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/webdriver)
[Selenium-Users Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/selenium-users)